# getting the day a file was last modified

Tags: android, android-file

I am writing a method that is supposed to check if the last file in a folder is a day old.

```
 private void checkForPhotoDelete() {
        File directory = new File("/sdcard/LC/images");
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        if(files.length>0){
            File lastFile = files[files.length-1];
            Date lastMod = new Date(lastFile.lastModified());

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int today = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); 
            Log.v("last modified","Last Modified Date : "+lastMod.getDay() + " vs "+today);
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

the problem is my file was last modified on tuesday and today is wed.  so i would expect my log to say:

> "Last Modified Date : 3 vs 4"

but instead it is saying 2 vs 4

Comment: Please NEVER hard-code your path to the device's external storage.  You should always use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to obtain the root path.

Comment: Im working on a project that will always be on the same device.. its not for the market but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try setting to the `calendar` instance the current date:

```
private void checkForPhotoDelete() {
        File directory = new File("/sdcard/LC/images");
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        if(files.length>0){
            File lastFile = files[files.length-1];
            long lastMod = lastFile.lastModified();

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            int today = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); 
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(lastMod);
            int lastModifyDay =  calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); 
            Log.v("last modified","Last Modified Date : "+ lastModifyDay + " vs "+today);
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Comment: calendar is giving the right day int i think maybe lastmodified getDay is returning a different day set?